# Meaning of Scribe symbols

Tags: symbols, facebook-scribe

I am starting to work with Scribe, I was reading the manual user, but I can't find anything about the symbols that Scribe uses on the Link column of the target side.

For example, I know what the check and the "X" means, but there are also diamonds, and other symbols that I don't understand.

Any manual or page where I can read all of this would be very helpul.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good [Scribe User Guide](https://openmind.scribesoftware.com/download/ScribeInsightUserGuide).

Hope it helps.

For Example:- Once you will download the e-Book and go to page 62, you can find details on graphical symbols.